SQLcl Error "no ocijdbc21 in java.library.path"
I'm trying to use SQLcl, but I am not able to enter my TNS credentials as I would as SQLPlus. In SQLPlus I could just enter a string:
"{User}"/"{Password}"@(DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = {Protocol})(HOST = {Host})(PORT = {Port}))(CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER = DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME = {Service})))

I believe it does allow me neither the usage of commands Ctrl+C, nor Ctrl+V.
This is what is shown first.

Then when I enter my credentials I get this error.

How can I set it up & be able to configure DB TNS Names (or whatever applies) & thus connect? Any idea on what's going on?

can you update your question to show what you're actually sending, and then also include the full error response?

@thatjeffsmith, updated the full error message. Not sure I understood what you mean with "what I'm actually sending". I'm just trying to log in.

i mean, HOW are you passing that TNS connect string to the SQL command?
at a sql prompt from sql /nolog, you could do connect user/password@server:port/service

@thatjeffsmith, I think that's what I'm missing. How can I set the tool to use "SQL \NOLOG"?

OK, now I was able to do it: when you say "use sql /nolog", you mean I need to run the application from Windows Run command (or CMD, I guess) adding that specification. Thanks.
